# Android Camera SurfaceView. How to Change Picture Resolution?

Tags: android

I´m trying to change the resolution of the camera when I using a surfaceview. I´m using a implementation like this: [url](http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/43414.aspx) . My camera has a 2592 x 1944 pixels resolution, but when I get byte[] from Camera and then convert to a Bitmap the Bitmap has 2048 x 1536. There is a way to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the camera parameters; in this case with [`Camera.Parameters.setPictureSize()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPictureSize%28int,%20int%29).

The basic workflow here is

```
Camera.Parameters cp = mCamera.getParameters(); // get the current params
cp.set...(); // change something
mCamera.setParameters(cp); // write the params back
```

*mCamera is your camera object in this case.*
*This is also documented in the `Camera` [class documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html). under step 2 and 3.*

Make sure that every resolution that you set via this function is supported. You can get a list of the resolutions that are supported on a device via `Camera.Parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes()`.

Comment: Ok, I select one picture size(Class Size) and set on the Camera with Camera.Parameters.setPictureSize(), but after takepicture I receive an byte array, and I set this size on the Bitmap options outWidth and outHeight. There is other way?

Comment: You receive a bytearray, yes. But what do you mean with outWidth? The byte-array is a compressed JPEG. If you want a bitmap, you have to uncompress it (like you probably did already). But then you get the resulting size automatically, you don't have to set anything dimension specific. Can you elaborate that some more please?

Comment: Sorry, I did a mistake, your steps works perfectly. Thank you for help.